# Bottom Align Images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align to last two images to the bottom with the first one but having no luck.

```
.image-wrap img {

width:100%;
height:auto;
positon:absolute;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
display: table-cell;}

.image-wrap {

text-align:center;
width: 100%;
height:auto;
position: relative;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

}

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/uvh7w/

Comment: Could please mention your requirement little more clear.What is that you want.:)Can you explain..Pardon my inability :)

Comment: Ah sorry! Those two images that sit beside the first large one, I would like those two to sit on the bottom rather than from the top.

Comment: its like that only for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines at the end of the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/RrLx7/.  This solution is more of a patch.  For a more comprehensive approach, a big chunk of your code will need some overhauling.  I'll leave it up to you to do so.

```
[class*='col-'] {
    float: none;
    padding-right: 20px; 
}

#hehe > .grid.grid-pad {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#hehe > .grid.grid-pad > * {
    display: table-cell;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```